# Getting File Not Found on Export of Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm getting a 404 file not found error when using the google drive v3 API. The file-Id I'm getting from google picker so I know the id is correct. The offending code is as following (javascript):

```
downloadFile: function () {
      var _this = this;
      gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: this.developerKey,
        clientId: this.clientId,
        discoveryDocs: ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest'],
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
      }).then(function () {
        // not working with private files
        gapi.client.setToken(_this.oauthToken);
        gapi.client.drive.files.export({
          'fileId': _this.selectedFileId,
          'mimeType': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log('success!');
          });
        }, function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
      }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
```

Funnily enough it doesn't happen with all files only private files. So I assume the file not found error is just a generic response back from google indicating I wasn't allowed to access the file.

Oddly enough doing a files.get works fine:

```
 gapi.client.drive.files.get({
         fileId: _this.selectedFileId,
       supportsTeamDrives: true
       }).then(function (response) {
         console.log('worked');
       }, function (error) {
           console.log('failed');
       });
```

Comment: check (a) that the access token you are using is for the same user as the picker, and (b) the file is a google doc, as opposed to a binary file.

Answer (score 2):

I saw this same error when I used the *https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file* permission: to get export to work you need to have at least the *https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly* permission granted to the OAuth token you are using.